# Flutter - Filter with favorite not working(show favorites only not working)

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

Whenever I press on show favorites only in my popupmenu, it shows only the first item in the list but not the particular item i marked as favorite

Below is the model of my product(**product.dart in providers folder**)

```
class Product with ChangeNotifier {
  final String id;
  final String title;
  final String description;
  final double price;
  final String imageUrl;
  bool isFavorite;

  Product({
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
    required this.description,
    required this.price,
    required this.imageUrl,
    this.isFavorite = false,
  });

  void toggleFavoriteStatus() {
    isFavorite = !isFavorite;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

I am using the provider state management in my app, below is the file that I am providing data from to my app which is the **products.dart in providers folder**

```
class Products with ChangeNotifier {
  final List<Product> _items = [
    Product(
      id: 'p1',
      title: 'Red Shirt',
      description: 'A red shirt - it is pretty red!',
      price: 29.99,
      imageUrl:
          'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/10/02/22/17/red-t-shirt-1710578_1280.jpg',
    ),
    Product(
      id: 'p2',
      title: 'Trousers',
      description: 'A nice pair of trousers.',
      price: 59.99,
      imageUrl:
          'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e8/Trousers%2C_dress_%28AM_1960.022-8%29.jpg/512px-Trousers%2C_dress_%28AM_1960.022-8%29.jpg',
    ),
    Product(
      id: 'p3',
      title: 'Yellow Scarf',
      description: 'Warm and cozy - exactly what you need for the winter.',
      price: 19.99,
      imageUrl:
          'https://live.staticflickr.com/4043/4438260868_cc79b3369d_z.jpg',
    ),
    Product(
      id: 'p4',
      title: 'A Pan',
      description: 'Prepare any meal you want.',
      price: 49.99,
      imageUrl:
          'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/14/Cast-Iron-Pan.jpg/1024px-Cast-Iron-Pan.jpg',
    ),
  ];

  List<Product> get favoriteItems {
    return _items.where((prodItem) => prodItem.isFavorite).toList(); // Supposed to return all prodItems where isFavorite is true
  }

  List<Product> get items {
    return [..._items];
  }

  Product findById(id) {
    return items.firstWhere((prod) => prod.id == id);
  }
}
```

As you can see above, I am creating two instances of the products to display whether the favorites(*by using the favoriteItems getter*) or all(*using items getter*)

Below is the file which manages which items to show whether the favorites or all by passing a bool which is **_showFavoritesOnly to the product_grid widget**

```
enum FilterOption { favorites, all }

class ProductsOverviewScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const ProductsOverviewScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ProductsOverviewScreen> createState() => _ProductsOverviewScreenState();
}

class _ProductsOverviewScreenState extends State<ProductsOverviewScreen> {
  var _showFavoritesOnly = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('MyShop'),
        actions: [
          PopupMenuButton(
            onSelected: (FilterOption selectedValue) {
              setState(() {
                if (selectedValue == FilterOption.favorites) {
                  _showFavoritesOnly = true;
                } else {
                  _showFavoritesOnly = false;
                }
              });
            },
            icon: const Icon(Icons.more_vert),
            itemBuilder: (_) => [
              const PopupMenuItem(
                child: Text('Show Favorites'),
                value: FilterOption.favorites,
              ),
              const PopupMenuItem(
                child: Text('Show All'),
                value: FilterOption.all,
              ),
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: ProductsGrid(showFavs: _showFavoritesOnly),
    );
  }
}
```

Below is the **product_grid.dart** file

```
class ProductsGrid extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool showFavs;
  const ProductsGrid({
    Key? key,
    required this.showFavs,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final productData = Provider.of<Products>(context);
    final products = showFavs ? productData.favoriteItems : productData.items;
    return GridView.builder(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
      itemCount: products.length,
      gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        childAspectRatio: 3 / 2,
        mainAxisSpacing: 10,
        crossAxisSpacing: 10,
      ),
      itemBuilder: (ctx, i) => ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
        value: products[i],
        child: const ProductItem(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Below is the **product_item.dart** file

```
class ProductItem extends StatelessWidget {
  const ProductItem({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final product = Provider.of<Product>(context, listen: false);
    return ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      child: GridTile(
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.pushNamed(context, ProductDetailScreen.id,
                arguments: product.id);
          },
          child: Image.network(
            product.imageUrl,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
        footer: GridTileBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.black87,
          leading: Consumer<Product>(
            builder: (ctx, product, _) => IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                product.isFavorite ? Icons.favorite : Icons.favorite_border,
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                product.toggleFavoriteStatus();
              },
              color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
            ),
          ),
          title: Text(
            product.title,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
          trailing: IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.shopping_cart),
            onPressed: () {},
            color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't work for you. I copied your code and it works fine for me, only I don't have your ProductItem widget to see what it does wrong, but instead of your ProductItem I used ElevatedButton that toggles favorite status of clicked item like this: `products[i].isFavorite = !products[i].isFavorite;`

Comment: I have added the product item. Can you please check for me?

Comment: Checked it, still works. ‍♂️

Comment: Wow, I am using chrome to run my app. is there any case that this might be the cause?

Comment: Works for me in Chrome also. Idk what's happening on your side...

Comment: so on your side, it displays the chosen favorite? or the first item in the list instead

Comment: It displays chosen favorites

Comment: Maybe the only difference there could be is that I am using MultiProvider like so: `MultiProvider(
          providers: [ ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => Products(),),], child: ProductsOverviewScreen(), )`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242362/discussion-between-samuel-and-ante-bule).

Answer (score 1):

in `product_item.dart` change listen from `false` to `true`.

```dart
final product = Provider.of<Product>(context, listen: true);
```

Comment: Hi! Please explain briefly what your code does and why it solves the problem. Thank you :)